# Nodes generator in python

Tags: python-3.x

How to generate the nodes for a list of elements by performing addition with each and single element of list with another. Like for a list

```
[2,7,4,5]
```

we get

```
[9,4,5][6,7,5][7,7,4][2,10,5][2,10,4][2,7,9]
```

Comment: Starting point: Use `itertools.combinations(range(len(mylist)), 2)` to generate the index pairs to sum. Not sure where stuff like `[2, 10, 4]` comes from though; no combination of your input elements sums to `10`...

Comment: I think your desired output is missing some values

Comment: My question is while iterating the heap is performed with the addition and the values are printed but it is returning the output print like for [2,7,4,5] it is giving [9,4,5] and it is performing operation for that instead of original heap. How to rectify that